# Facebook graph api - interest found on facebook, but not via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find a specific interests for targeting via facebook api. My request is following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?type=audienceinterest&q=showbuzz.hr&access_token={ACCESSTOKEN}
```

Facebook documentation states:

> Use type= audienceinterest to get
>   possible IDs as Targeting Options and use the returned id to specify.

When i search for term "showbuzz.hr" it returns 0 results, but if i try to search same keyword as target when publishing post via facebook page, it finds it without any problem.

Only way i can find showbuzz.hr is when i use type=page or type=adworkemployer, but those are not suitable for post interests when using api.

Am I doing something wrong here? Why some keywords can be targeted via facebook, but not via api?
Is that a bug or facebook decision?